# Obtain eigenvectors of ellipsis resulting from the intersection between ellipsoid and plane using sympy

Tags: python, geometry, sympy

Given an ellipsoid with eigenvectors, eigenvalues, centroid, and a plane, I am trying to find the eigenvectors of the ellipse that result from the intersection of the plane and the ellipsoid (if this ellipse exists). I am kind of stuck using Sympy at the moment.
Take the following example data:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.solvers import solve

centroid = np.array([313.81153387, 252.73655237,  78.81324428])
eigenvectors = np.array([[-0.17245704,  0.75883261,  0.62803792],
       [-0.82066049, -0.46331271,  0.33445133],
       [ 0.54477053, -0.45772742,  0.70264548]]) # where each row is one eigenvector
eigenvalues = np.array([4.03632232, 3.80325721, 7.21909427])
# Plane equation: z = 78

coords = symbols('x_prime y_prime z_prime', positive = True)
z_coor, y_coor, x_coor = np.dot(eigenvectors, coords)

# Ellipsoids have a standard form of: 
# (x - h)^2 / a^2 + (y - i)^2 / b^2 + (z - j)^2 / c^2 = 1

ellipsoid_eq_rotated = ((x_coor - centroid[0])**2 / eigenvalues[0]) + \
                       ((y_coor - centroid[1])**2 / eigenvalues[1]) + \
                       ((z_coor - centroid[2])**2 / eigenvalues[2]) - 1

intersection_eq = ellipsoid_eq_rotated.subs(z_coor, 78)
intersection_points = solve(intersection_eq, (x_coor, y_coor))
```

However, this gives me an empty array as a result (i.e. no solutions).
As I intersect the ellipsoid right at its centroid, this doesn't make sense.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `solve` a single equation in three variables and requesting the solution for two *expressions*. When in doubt, print it out. You also did not use the expression `intersection_eq`.

I would also recommend only using SymPy as in

```py
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.solvers import solve

centroid = [313.81153387, 252.73655237,  78.81324428]
eigenvectors = [[-0.17245704,  0.75883261,  0.62803792],
       [-0.82066049, -0.46331271,  0.33445133],
       [ 0.54477053, -0.45772742,  0.70264548]] # where each row is one eigenvector
eigenvalues = [4.03632232, 3.80325721, 7.21909427]
# Plane equation: z = 78

coords = symbols('x_prime y_prime z_prime', positive = True)
z_coor, y_coor, x_coor = Matrix(eigenvectors)*Matrix(coords)

# Ellipsoids have a standard form of: 
# (x - h)^2 / a^2 + (y - i)^2 / b^2 + (z - j)^2 / c^2 = 1

ellipsoid_eq_rotated = ((x_coor - centroid[0])**2 / eigenvalues[0]) + \
                       ((y_coor - centroid[1])**2 / eigenvalues[1]) + \
                       ((z_coor - centroid[2])**2 / eigenvalues[2]) - 1

intersection_eq = ellipsoid_eq_rotated.subs(z_coor, 78)
intersection_points = solve(ellipsoid_eq_rotated, (x_coor, y_coor))
```

(The above has the same problems as before but now only uses SymPy.)

Comment: I copied my MWE incorrectly, thanks for pointing it out. I adapted my code so intersection_eq is used in solve. What do you mean by "you pass it two expressions"? I just want a solution expressed in x and y coordinates.

Comment: `coords` contains your variables, and `x_coor`, an expression in those variables.